# VBScript unable to close launched IE browser after countdown

Tags: html, internet-explorer, vbscript, countdown, wsh

## Problem

I can't trigger an auto-closing of the browser that my VBS script opens:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("Winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor where DeviceID = 'DesktopMonitor1'",,0)
For Each objItem in colItems
  intHorizontal = objItem.ScreenWidth
  intVertical = objItem.ScreenHeight
Next

objIE.Visible = 1
objIE.Navigate "D:\localpath\filename.htm"

objShell.AppActivate objIE

Do Until VarType(objIE) = 9
  WScript.Sleep 1000
  'For Each p In colItems
  'p.Terminate
  'Next

  'objIE.Quit
Loop
objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
```

When I try `objIE.Quit`, **I get the error `The object invoked has disconnected from its clients` (80010108)**. I try to invoke the object before disconnection but nothing happens:

```
Do Until VarType(objIE) = 9
  WScript.Sleep 60000
  objIE.Quit
Loop
```

## Need

I need a script that opens my webpage, does a 1 minute countdown, then close the IE browser.

## Constraints

1. Should not be using kill process
2. Should only close the correct browser
3. Should not use JS because the default machine settings disabled them
   a. For countdown without JS, I'm using a gif on the webpage as a workaround
4. htm has to be local. objIE.Quit works when the htm is hosted online

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem lies with local htm files. While I couldn't find a solution, I've changed my scripts to HTA instead, and it now works well:

### VBS

```
Const SHOW_ACTIVE_APP = 1 
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
objShell.Run ("filename.hta") &, SHOW_ACTIVE_APP, True 
Wscript.Quit
```

### HTA

```
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     APPLICATIONNAME="AppName"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="no"  
     ICON="" 
     SCROLL="no"
     CAPTION="yes"
     >
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>

    <title>Information Security</title>
    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Window_onLoad
            window.resizeTo 680,390
        End Sub 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- html content -->
</body>
```